SQL: Join based on closest date
I have the two following tables:
CREATE TABLE my_table1 (
    color VARCHAR(50),
    d1 DATE,
    var1 VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO my_table1 (color, d1, var1)
VALUES
    ('red', '2010-01-01', 'a'),
    ('red', '2011-01-01', 'b'),
    ('red', '2012-01-01', 'c'),
    ('red', '2013-01-01', 'b'),
    ('blue', '2013-01-01', 'a'),
    ('blue', '2014-01-01', 'd'),
    ('blue', '2015-01-01', 'f'),
    ('green', '2020-01-01', 'a');


CREATE TABLE my_table2 (
    color VARCHAR(50),
    d2 DATE,
    var2 VARCHAR(50)
);


INSERT INTO my_table2 (color, d2, var2)
VALUES
    ('red', '2008-01-01', 'zz'),
    ('red', '2020-01-01', 'cc'),
    ('blue', '1999-01-01', 'xx'),
    ('blue', '2005-01-01', 'yy'),
    ('purple', '2022-01-01', 'hh');

These tables look like this:
| color |     d1     | var1 |
|-------|------------|------|
|  red  | 2010-01-01 |   a  |
|  red  | 2011-01-01 |   b  |
|  red  | 2012-01-01 |   c  |
|  red  | 2013-01-01 |   b  |
| blue  | 2013-01-01 |   a  |
| blue  | 2014-01-01 |   d  |
| blue  | 2015-01-01 |   f  |
| green | 2020-01-01 |   a  |


| color  |     d2     | var2 |
|--------|------------|------|
|  red   | 2008-01-01 |  zz  |
|  red   | 2020-01-01 |  cc  |
|  blue  | 1999-01-01 |  xx  |
|  blue  | 2005-01-01 |  yy  |
| purple | 2022-01-01 |  hh  |

I am trying to accomplish the following task:

Using my_table2 as the main table, I want to join to my_table1 where color=color and d1 is closest to d2
After the join, the columns from my_table1 should be called closest_color, closest_d1, closest_var1
The final result should have the same number of rows as my_table2 (purple would have all NULLS)

I thought of using a function that can take the absolute value of the date differences and then do a full outer left join to make sure all rows from my_table2 are captured - and then use window functions to rank/partition to identify the smallest difference:
WITH closest_dates AS (
    SELECT 
        t2.color, 
        t2.d2, 
        t2.var2, 
        t1.color AS closest_color, 
        t1.d1 AS closest_d1, 
        t1.var1 AS closest_var1,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t2.color, t2.d2 ORDER BY ABS(extract(day from( t2.d2 - t1.d1)))) as rn
    FROM 
        my_table2 t2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        my_table1 t1
    ON 
        t1.color = t2.color
)
SELECT 
    color, 
    d2, 
    var2, 
    closest_color, 
    closest_d1, 
    closest_var1
FROM 
    closest_dates
WHERE 
    rn = 1;

I am not sure how to perform absolute date differences in Netezza - can someone please show me how to do this correctly?
Thanks!

Row_number is an older design pattern; though still widely used since not everything supports lateral/outer apply yet.   But window functions have been around for years now... You could accomplish this using a table value function "Lateral"  IBM example: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=clause-lateral-derived-tables  I just answered a similar quesiton for postgres https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78528900/postgre-sql-conditional-join-between-tables-and-leave-the-nearest-date-only/78529395#78529395

@ xQbert: thank you so much for your reply! do you think my answer looks correct to you?

select * from
(
   select *,
          d1-d2 as date_difference,
          row_number() over ( partition by color, var2
                              order by     date_difference
                            )

   from my_table2 left outer join my_table1 using (color)

)  sub1

where row_number = 1

order by 1,2,3,4;

