Postgre SQL: Conditional join between tables and leave the nearest date only
I am pulling this query os user 'USv3s_tggf19' in a PostgreSQL database server.
select us.id as user_step_id, us.goal_id, us.user_id, us.created_datetime
, m.mod_code, m.modified_datetime
from database.user_steps us
left join database.mods m on
us.goal_id = m.goal_id 
where us.user_id like 'USv3s_tggf19'


An this is the table that I have:

As you can see, because in the database.mods table there are duplicated records that relate to different modifications of the same thing, I end up having duplicate records in my output, which is expected.
Now, my intention is to leave the record that is closest in m.modified_date to us.created_datetime. And my end result should look something like this:

I've been trying different things looking in other responses and this query is the one that looks closest, but it does not return me any information from the mods table.
select us.id as user_step_id, us.goal_id, us.user_id, us.created_datetime
, m.mod_code, m.modified_datetime
from database.user_steps us
left join database.mods m on
us.goal_id = m.goal_id 
and us.created_datetime = (select max(m.modified_datetime) from database.mods m  where m.modified_datetime < us.created_datetime)
where us.user_id like 'USv3s_tggf19'

I'd appreciate any guidance with this.

the record that is "closest" in m.modified_date.... closest before? Closest after or closest absolute?  My "feeling" is I'd use a lateral join  and a subquery with correlation to get the closest record from database.mods.  Lateral is a table value function which runs a subquery for each record in the outer table returning the record(s) for which correlation has been defined.  One can use order by and limit to control the number of records returned.  Before lateral, one would use a row number and correlation .

What version of Postgresql?

PostgreSQL 12.17

I'm not familiar with lateral joins, will investigate.

Still need to understand what you mean by "closest" as well.  Closest before, after or absolute?  and if there's a tie, what wins?

Sorry, closest after, created_datetime should be closest after modified_datetime, as in the desired output in the example.

@UnaiVicente for the community to be able to help you with this problem is necessary that you provide a minimal reproducible example, dummy data on all the tables involved and expected result in text, not on images, so info can be easily copied and pasted.

@PepeNO It's a query to a postgre server, not a data manipulation procedure, forgive me but I have no idea how I would put here a reproducible example without giving access to my server to all the community, pal :) My hope is someone with expertise can understand the logic that needs to be applied and tell me what I am not doing right in my proposed solution.

We just need the sampe data and a DDL to create the tables.  3rd party tools  such as https://dbfiddle.uk work great for this and https://dbfiddle.uk/uix83qrI is an example using similar data with similar table structure reverse engineered from what you've provided.  We can take the ouput of those tables use ascii-table generator to "paste" in the tables and generate an ascii table iwth data as shown in my answer.

As to why your solution isn't working.  your sub query isn't by goal ID so it only returns the max. It's a scaler value reutnring only 1 value, not one value per goal.  the Lateral solves this problem.

Understood, very appreciative.

Working dbfiddleuk example
I dumbed down the data to help me understand it a bit; but this SQL should be close.
More info on Lateral

Prior to lateral design pattern, one would use subqueries and row numbers and coorlation to do this.

Prior to using row_number one would use a inline view to get the max/min date for each goal_id and then join this back to the base set from mods to get all the columns.


Just different design patterns over the ages.
Lateral basically says:
-- For each row in user_Steps, get the related mods for that goal (correlation) having the earliest modified date (again correlation) after the created date.
SELECT us.id as user_step_id, us.goal_id, us.user_id, us.created_datetime
, m.mod_code, m.modified_datetime
FROM user_steps us
LEFT join LATERAL (SELECT mod_Code, goal_ID, modified_datetime 
                   FROM mods a 
                   WHERE a.modified_DateTime < us.created_datetime
                     and us.goal_id = a.goal_id 
                   ORDER BY a.modified_DateTime desc
                   LIMIT 1) m
  on true 
WHERE us.user_id = 'A'

For future reference you could use the dbfiddle.uk to mock up an example or use  https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to mock up text tables.
Giving us: (I used ascii tables (github.io link above) to generate via a copy and paste results from the dbfiddle.uk)
+--------------+---------+---------+------------------+----------+-------------------+
| user_step_id | goal_id | user_id | created_datetime | mod_code | modified_datetime |
+--------------+---------+---------+------------------+----------+-------------------+
| A            | A.1     | A       | 2024-05-10       | B2       | 2023-09-08        |
| B            | B.1     | A       | 2024-04-26       | I10      | 2024-02-02        |
| C            | C.1     | A       | 2024-03-12       | B5       | 2023-09-08        |
| D            | D.1     | A       | 2024-03-01       | I10      | 2024-02-02        |
| E            | E.1     | A       | 2024-02-16       | I10      | 2024-02-02        |
+--------------+---------+---------+------------------+----------+-------------------+

This assumes goal_ID and date comparison is the only relationship needed between user_steps and mods and you only want the most recent mod record after the created date.  but you could change the lmit to be 2 or change the order to ascending if you want the first one after that date.
Try it out; if it's not working let us know what's not working/meeting expectations.  Ask questions if you don't understand something; I'd be happy to explain it!

It works perfectly, thank you for this super comprehensive response.

glad to be of service! I recommend playing around with the ascii table generator and dbfiddle.uk or similar when /if you have SQL questions in the future.  It helps us better understand the problem and gives us a space to play around and help out.

Will definitely do, this was my first SQL question in stackoverflow so great to know this for future reference, thanks @xQbert, very very helpful!
